# How can I run a .java file from a java program and capture the output so I can compare what that java program outputs to a String

Tags: java

To clarify, I'm trying to write a program that grades if a program is run correctly. When a .java file is in the same directory, it runs the file and captures the output to a String so it can check if it is the right answer.

The files that are entered will grab data from a text file, manipulate it, and out.print(); so the program needs to be able to capture the output to see if the program submitted works and its answers match a database of answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use process class to run any executable in java code.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" // command to execute java code");

process.waitFor();
```

It will execute any executable.

process object will give different type of streams.

```
process.getInputStream();

process.getOutputStream();

process.getErrorStream();
```

from that stream you can retrieve the output.